# How can drawing routines be optimized to achieve the maximum refresh rate in Windows CE?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, mfc, windows-ce

In my application i am drawing some set of lines (like a vertical graph), and the refresh rate will be around 30 times in a second. I have calculated the performance and it is taking 400 milliseconds to draw complete lines, but this won't be fast enough since we have to refresh the screen every 34 milliseconds.

I am drawing on CDC.

We will be drawing on a Windows CE device with a 400 MHz processor. Drawing involves the simple MFC APIs like `MoveTo`, `LineTo`, `FillRect`, etc. on DC of View:

```
CDC* pDC = GetDC(); //draw vertical line from one end of screen to the other 
pDC->MoveTo(some xy Cordinates);
pDC->LineTo(some xy Points);
```

How we can optimize the drawing routines? Please suggest any pointers.

Comment: If you don't tell us how you are drawing, or why it is taking 400ms, we can't really tell you how to make it faster.  Show some code, and explain why lines take 400ms.

Comment: You will probably have to switch to OpenGL ES or Direct3D Mobile in order to get your framerate up.  What processor are you using?  If it doesn't have a graphics accelerator, you may be out of luck.  MFC surely isn't helping either.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows Vista, GDI operations (other than BitBlt) are no longer hardware accelerated, but done in software.

To get the performance you need, you probably need to use Direct3D or OpenGl.

All though [this msdn document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implies that, since NT 6.1, hw acceleration of GDI is back on the table. Still I expect the vector based APIs offered by OpenGL and D3D should perform far more reliably - GDI line drawing is not something driver writers strive to optimize.

---

In answer to the update re Windows CE being the target: [Direct X](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834186.aspx) has apparently been available on Windows CE since at least CE 2.1

Im still betting that GDI is not particularly hw accelerated on CE; if there is any hw support at all, DirectX would be the way to access it.

Comment: We will be drawing on Wince device, which has 400Mhz processor, Drawing involve the simple MFC API like(Moveto ,LineTo,FillRect and all) on CDC*pDC of View;

Comment: We will be drawing on Wince device, which has 400Mhz processor, Drawing involve the simple MFC API like(Moveto ,LineTo,FillRect and all) on DC of View; 
CDC* pDC = GetDC();
//draw line vertical line from one end of screen to other other end
pDC->MoveTo(some xy Cordinates);
pDC->LineTo(some xy Points);

Comment: @mukesh: Embedded systems running Windows CE is a very different environment than the Win32 API on desktops. I've taken the liberty of updating the question for you.