# Alternate for MoveTo and LineTo in Windows CE, MFC

Tags: mfc, windows-ce, gdi

Hi i am working on some high resolution display features in which have to draw the vertical line , i am using Moveto() and lineTO() , but it is much time taking...
can anyone suggest me , what we can use instead of it ...to optimize the performance...

see the scene is , in order to draw 100 Vertical lines it is taking 84ms time, we need to reduce it to 5 ms something..

please refer me any alternate fot that.

Thanks,

Mukesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can drawing routines be optimized to achieve the maximum refresh rate in Windows CE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524527/how-can-drawing-routines-be-optimized-to-achieve-the-maximum-refresh-rate-in-wind)

Comment: You already asked this exact same question. If GDI is slow, then the only alternative is D3D.

Comment: @Chris Becke off-screen draw followed by blt will be fast, or do you disagree with that analysis?

Comment: Why would that be faster? if the CE device has no gdi hw acceleration, then you have doubled the workload: it now has to draw the lines AND copy memory around. Using backbuffers has always been slower: but they're used because they eliminate tearing and overpainting artifacts.

Comment: @Chris hmm, that's news to me, not that I doubt you

Comment: @Chris I wonder if it would be quicker then to work with the bits directly in memory rather than use GDI LineTo and then blt to the screen?

Comment: GDI's software line drawing routines date from windows 3.1 - they've always made the tradeoff of speed over quality. I doubt there are faster software line drawing routines than the ones found in GDI.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use GDI+ which should be faster, well, you need to try if it really fits your need :-)

Here is a link to integrate GDI+ with MFC: [Using GDI+ with MFC or native C/C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/gdi__and_mfc.aspx)

Comment: GDI+ has a reputation for being slow.

Answer (score 0):

The first step would probably be to try [`CDC::PolyPolyline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d29f3yyh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It's by *far* the easiest modification to make, and might be sufficient. Deciding on the next step after that will probably be *much* more difficult. The obvious possibilities would be GDI+, OpenGL, and DirectX Graphics. I've listed those in approximately increasing order of complexity to use, and likelihood that they'll give you the speed increase you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Rectangle function that may be useful to you if those vertical lines actually make rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 100 lines should take that long to draw. Is there something else that you aren't telling us. Are you drawing direct to a screen DC? Have you tried drawing to offscreen bitmap and then blt-ing to the screen?

Comment: We are using the draw on WinCe device... need to implement some Filled graph thing, in which have to draw the lines from one end to other end. 

@david We haven't tried for offscreen drawing and bit-ing to the main DC. but i dont think so this will make big effect on that...anyhow u need to move points and draw.

Comment: @mukesh how on earth could you omit that you are using CE?!!! Please edit your question to say so, and include details of the actual device being used. Off screen drawing should make a big difference. LineTo will be very fast on an in-memory bitmap. Please try it.